# Angular JS Service Call returns not an array

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to create a service that returns coordinates for a heatmap in Angular JS

Here is the service:

```
var traffic = angular.module('traffic', ['ngMap'])
.factory('checkpointService', function($q){
  return function($scope, $http){
    var d = $q.defer();
      $http.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/traffic/get/?end=" + $scope.endDateTime + "&format=json&search=Search&start=" + $scope.startDateTime)
       .then(function(response) {
              var points = []
              angular.forEach(response.data, function(value, key) {
                console.log("Response: " + JSON.stringify(response))
                points.push(new google.maps.LatLng(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(value))["lat"], JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(value))["long"]))
            });
            //d.resolve(points)
            console.log("Points: " + points)
            return points;
          });


    }
  });
```

and the call:

```
    var points = new Array();
    points = checkpointService($scope, $http)
    heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
        data: points,
        map: $scope.map

  });
```

The error is "not an Array".

I know that the $http call is asynchronous and thus a promise is used. I have also tried using $q.defer:

```
.factory('checkpointService', function($q){
  return function($scope, $http){
    var d = $q.defer();
      $http.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/traffic/get/?end=" + $scope.endDateTime + "&format=json&search=Search&start=" + $scope.startDateTime)
       .then(function(response) {
              var points = []
              angular.forEach(response.data, function(value, key) {
                console.log("Response: " + JSON.stringify(response))
                points.push(new google.maps.LatLng(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(value))["lat"], JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(value))["long"]))
            });
            d.resolve(points)
            console.log("Points: " + points)
            return d.promise;
          });


    }
  });
```

and call:

```
var points = [];
    points = checkpointService($scope, $http)
    points.then(function(){
    heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
        data: points,
        map: $scope.map

  })});
```

In this instance, the error is instead "cannot read property 'then' of undefined".

I realize that there are similar questions; I've read them and the documentation. I'm still struggling to understand. I know that the $http call in the service is successful. However, I believe points in the heatmap data parameter is empty. Simply, the service should return an array of LatLng points for a heatmap.

Comment: You don't need to wrap `$http` inside a `defer`, since it already returns a promise.  The problem is that you declared your `points []` *inside* your callback function, but tried to return it from the outer function, before the promise has even finished;  The callback hasn't run yet, and `points` isn't reachable.

Comment: in most cases, you see `return $http ...` in services, and the variable assignment is done in the controller.

Comment: These comments was also helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your first approach, you were very close.

```
var traffic = angular.module('traffic', ['ngMap'])
    .factory('checkpointService', function ($q) {
        return function ($scope, $http) {
            return $http.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/traffic/get/?end=" + $scope.endDateTime + "&format=json&search=Search&start=" + $scope.startDateTime)
                .then(function (response) {
                    var points = []
                    angular.forEach(response.data, function (value, key) {
                        console.log("Response: " + JSON.stringify(response))
                        points.push(new google.maps.LatLng(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(value))["lat"], JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(value))["long"]))
                    });
                    //d.resolve(points)
                    console.log("Points: " + points)
                    return points;
                });


        }
    });


checkpointService($scope, $http).then(function (points) {
    heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
        data: points,
        map: $scope.map

    });
});
```

What I changed:

1. Made sure the checkpointService function returns the $http promise.
2. Google maps bit is now within the success handler of the promise. This handler receives the points array that you created in the service as the first argument. You pass that array to the Google maps API.
3. Removed the $q.defer() bit since that is no longer necessary.